# Adding a value to a jquery tree object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have an object like that.

```
var t = {
    "obj1": {
        "obj1.1": "test",
        "obj1.2": {
            "obj1.1.1": null, // <-- "obj1.1.1" has to have a value.
            "obj1.1.2": "test"
        }
    }
};
```

And a path to the node where I'd like to add a value, i.e.:

```
var path = ['obj1', 'obj1.1', 'test'];
```

How do I add the value programmatically?

Comment: Um, you object is messed up. Don't you want arrays? `"obj1.2" : []`

Comment: which value and where you want to add it ?

Comment: your object as defined is wrong. Please post the real code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function setDeepValue(obj, value, path) {
    if(path.length > 1){
        var p=path.shift();
        if(obj[p]==null || typeof obj[p]!== 'object'){
            obj[p] = {};
        }
        setDeepValue(obj[p], value, path);
    }else{
        obj[path[0]] = value;
    }
}

var obj = {};
var path = ['obj1', 'obj1.1'];
setDeepValue(obj, 'test', path);
console.log(obj); // {"obj1":{"obj1.1":"test"}}
```

You will however need to fix your object:

```
var t = {
    "obj1": {
        "obj1.1": "test",
        "obj1.2": {
            "obj1.1.1": null, // <-- "obj1.1.1" has to have a value.
            "obj1.1.2": "test"
        }
    }
};
```

A object can't have a key without a value, so `"obj1.1.1"` will have to have a value, even if it's `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this object

```
var obj = {
      "obj1" : {
          "obj1.1" : "",
          "obj1.2" : {
             "obj1.1.1" : "",
             "obj1.1.2" : ""
             }
          }
      }

var path = ['obj1', 'obj1.1', 'test'];
```

the algorithm is:

```
var el = obj;
for(var i = 0; i < path.length-2; i++) {
     el = el[path[i]]; 
}
el[path[i]] = path[i+1];
```

or as function

```
function setpath(obj,path) {
    var el = obj;
    for(var i = 0; i < path.length-2; i++) {
        console.log(i+"="+path[i]);
         el = el[path[i]]; 
    }
    el[path[i]] = path[i+1];
    console.log(el);
}

setpath(obj,['obj1', 'obj1.1', 'test']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tree = {
    "obj1": {
        "obj1.1": "test",
        "obj1.2": {
            "obj1.1.1": null,
            "obj1.1.2": "test"
        }
    }
};

var path = ['obj1', 'obj1.1', 'test'];
```

A static way of setting 'test':

```
tree[path[0]][path[1]] = path[2];
```

A static way of replacing 'test' with newObj:

```
var newObj = { ... };
tree[path[0]][path[1]][path[2]] = newObj;
```